# 13 week old kitten will not stop sucking on me

Tags: cats, behavior

I have a 13 week old kitten, which I took away from her mama when she was 9 weeks old. She stopped nursing from her mom and started sucking on my ear lobes and neck (and sometimes the tip of my fingers). She is definitely a healthy happy kitty! She only does this when she's ready to go to sleep. I feel like I can't bond with her because I'm constantly setting her down on the floor or pushing her off my earlobes. It's like I give the Tabby more attention than I give her. (She's a Calico.) Is this normal? Will she eventually stop, or do I need to double check on her health? I don't think shes stressed, she will only fight me when she's being put down. Until I give her something to suck on, she wins every time.... How do I get her to stop sucking on me?

Comment: Welcome to Pets! If you have a minute, please take the [tour] and have a look at the [help]. Your question is one never-ending string of words without any punctuation, which makes it very hard to understand. Could you please [edit] your question to format it in sentences and paragraphs to make it more understandable?

Answer (score 1):

Allow it her. She still thinks, you are now her mom.

In general, you are very alien for her, she simply doesn't have any instinctual idea, what are you. But you seem to behave like her mommy, and now she thinks, you are her mommy.

If it is not disgusting, allow her to play with you.

**This is a crucial period for she, the negative experiences what she collects now from you, might she alienate from you for life.** What she now learns, will in her in her whole life. Later will she be mentally incapable to learn such things, like humans are not bad, or that you love she.

The time until the cats are capable to understand causality, is 5 seconds. (This is why it is reasonless to punish a cat for anything after more than 5 seconds - she won't understand, why she got it. She will think that you attacked she for no reason.)

On this reason, I would suggest: **allow her to lick you for 5 seconds**. After that, take she up and put to a different location on you - still on you, but not more in a position where she could still lick you. The thinking of the cats is very location-oriented - if you move she to another place, she understands very well: "My mom wants me to be here".

Sometimes around a half year (latest as she would start to heat), she will forget their kitten behaviors, including the licking, but she will still love you. So better you treated she as a kitten, so better will she love you, and this love will be eternal.